# How to create a installation package from my j2me project with large number of files

Tags: jar, java-me, bluetooth, packaging

I have a project in **J2ME**, writing in net beans 6.9.1
My project is about opening a mp3 file from with a string format file name that generates with a function (not browsing) and plays it.

I have created this program and it works in simulator.
My problem is, how to send all these 300 files to mobile device?

It should be simple to send between users with Bluetooth in future.
I want to know is there any way to package all files in one file and extract them when installing in mobile device?
Or what is the correct way to to that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy the files JAR and JAD from "project_dir/dist" into your mobile then install it.

Comment: Thank you Jaffer. It worked. I saw the content of Jar file with Winrar.exe. So how can I use on of my files within the jar file. I should open the mp3 file an play it. I used the file name in a string variable like fileName="/song.mp3", and my song.mp3 file is located in  src folder. I added src folder to package and it is present in jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Packaging all those 300 mp3 files in your app will result in large `jar` file size. As you know most of the Java ME mobile phones have very less memory allocated for installing Java ME apps. It is better to provide an option to download all those files form server to SD card when a person use the app for first time.

Comment: Thank you Jose. It is a very good idea. But I dont have any knowledge about it. So I will search about "Downloading file from server to SD card". If you have any sample, please help me. Thnx again.

Answer (score 0):

As Sabin said, it is not a good solution to have all your audio files inside your application, assuming you are using Mobile RMS (Record Management System) which is very limited in size and capabilities; it is better to add a code to open them from your SD card or stream them from server.

Comment: It should be offline and no connection should be requested. So, I need to give my users an offline jar file,or any other solution to give my users an installation package. The first solution with jar file is so simple and I will try it as first phase. But for better performance i will develop it as you two recommend. So will you send me a sample or some help to do what you recommend? 1. How to store large number of files in SD, and 2. How to access them in run mode?

Comment: Read about OBDC driver and you may download it from here [link](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)
Or read about Java Driver; using these drivers you will be able to create external database easily to access without affecting the application performance; after all you are talking about Symbian devices what's your processing power ? 400 MHz ? still will exhaust the device to read and run the files.